# Dependency injection container OR passing the objects via constructor?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

which way is the best generally?

This:

```
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', array(
  'auth'     => 'login',
  'username' => 'foo',
  'password' => 'bar',
  'ssl'      => 'ssl',
  'port'     => 465,
));

$mailer = new Zend_Mail();
$mailer->setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

or:

```
class Container
{
  public function getMailTransport()
  {
    return new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', array(
      'auth'     => 'login',
      'username' => 'foo',
      'password' => 'bar',
      'ssl'      => 'ssl',
      'port'     => 465,
    ));
  }

  public function getMailer()
  {
    $mailer = new Zend_Mail();
    $mailer->setDefaultTransport($this->getMailTransport());

    return $mailer;
  }
}
$container = new Container();
$mailer = $container->getMailer();
```

codes from here: http://fabien.potencier.org/do-you-need-a-dependency-injection-container.html

Comment: For larger applications and when using external DI configuration, DI is really *required* or you would not prevail application.

Comment: While this is primarily opinion based. DI configuration is required as @PeterM said. Basically, with your DI example, you can change freely change your Mailer now without having to touch any other code. Even on small projects if there is any chance the technology you are using could change or you would want to update it in the future. Use DI.